# setOnClickListener not working as expected

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

First of all, I'm a newbie to android.

I have three activities in my Application. i.e, **MainActivity, TC and navigation_drawer.**

The user enters in MainActivity in the beginning, provided his/her name and enters TC on a button click (Working perfectly fine). Here inside TC there are two buttons "Agree", "Do not Agree" as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TC">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/agree"
        android:text="Agree"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/not_agree"
        android:text="Do not Agree"
        android:layout_below="@id/agree"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, if the user clicks on **Agree** it should go to **navigation_drawer** and if clicked on **Do not agree** it should go back to **MainActivity**. The code for it is:

```
public class TC extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button Agree, NotAgree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_t_c);

        Agree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.agree);
        NotAgree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.not_agree);

        Agree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TC.this, "Agree", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(TC.this, navigation_drawer.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        NotAgree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TC.this, "Not Agree", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(TC.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***Toast was added just to check if the right method was called or no (And it is calling the right method)***

The AndroidManifest.xml contains(I am not sure if this will help):

```
        <activity android:name=".TC" android:noHistory="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".navigation_drawer" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The problem is, for some reason no matter which button I click it always redirects to **navigation_drawer** also for both the buttons the Toast message was shown **as expected.**

I do not know what am I missing here, please suggest a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show the java code where you assigned a reference to your button and the navigation_drawer code

Comment: ```Button Agree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.agree);``` Also make sure your linked to the correct xml. Set content view.

Comment: Is `navigation_drawer` an Activity? If it is, it's some odd naming.

Comment: @ThomasMorris I had already initialized the buttons. Forgot to add it in the code. Added it now.

Comment: @abstractArrow Will make a note of that :D

Comment: Can you share the entire XML?

Comment: @speedster01 Sure. I have added it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in logcat? Or even warnings for that matter.

Comment: Can you post `MainActivity` and `navigation_drawer` too?

Comment: You only have one activity in your manifest so where is your code running from? If its main activity it will just restart the main activity. So add another activity for what you want to do then start that. ```Intent myIntent = new Intent(this_activity.this, next_activity.class);``` Then ```this_activity.this.startActivity(myIntent);``` Followed by ```finish();```

Comment: Remove `android:noHistory="true"` for MainActivity from Manifest and instead of calling intent and starting an activity, just place `TC.this.finish()` removing what you have currently in `NotAgree` button `OnclickListener`.

Comment: One thing more, why are you using a whole `Activity` just to show the user the Terms and Conditions? Why can'y you go for a `AlertDialog` preferably with Custom Layout?

Comment: @Lalit Fauzdar, activities could be pretty handy. You can create one `Activity` and use it everytime you need to display dialog. What's more, you can adjust them to show one, two, three or more additional buttons or other `Views` and take appropriate action inside `onActivityResult()` when you get back. You just need to pass text to display by `Intent`. Also (in my opinion) activities are much easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code and should work but it seems like you are starting the `navigation_drawer` activity in both button clicks.

So I suggest you declare and initialize both button's `Intent` variables outside the `setOnClickListner()` block by giving each `Intent` variables different name such as `intent1` and `intent2` and try running it again.

Answer (score 0):

test this :

remove `android:noHistory="true"` in `Manifest`

and after `startActivity(....)` call `finish()`